# How to detect a postcode (5-7 char) always at the right of a string, and insert a SPACE before it, in a SQL update statement

Tags: sql, sql-server

However before the space is inserted, the expression needs to check that its not already inerted the space, so we do not end up with 2 spaces, then 3 and so on, so this...

```
HAUGHTON HOUSEALFORDAB33 8NA
BURIAL GROUNDTOUGHALFORDAB33 8ER
TORRYCRIEN CROFTGLENKINDIEALFORDAB33 8SQ
KIRKTON FORBESALFORDG1 1DN
```

Would become...

```
HAUGHTON HOUSEALFORD AB33 8NA
BURIAL GROUNDTOUGHALFORD AB33 8ER
TORRYCRIEN CROFTGLENKINDIEALFORD AB33 8SQ
KIRKTON FORBESALFORD G1 1DN
```

This could be tricky - maybe in some way combining with REGEX, however, because letters are before the first letter in POSTCODE it may need to detect a valid POSTCODE

Comment: Why not *remove* the space(s) first and then inject the space where it needs to be?

Comment: How do you detect a post code? How do I know `FORBESALFORDG1` should become `FORBESALFORD G1` and not `FORBESALFOR DG1`

Comment: This will be an ugly mess to handle on SQL Server.  If you really must do this replacement, I suggest using regular expressions.  They are not available on SQL Server though.

Comment: Do you mean remove the first space to the right, if one did that, we still need to detect a valid postcode then insert before postcode the space. But postcodes can be 5 or 6 or 7 long. So its a guess if we did that. I'm starting to think only way is a regex to detect then insert space of not already one there (i.e. ran before on that same data)

Comment: Please define what a post code is. Why is `G1` a post code and `DG1` is not?

Comment: Post codes have different formats in different countries. For a *specific fixed width format* you could write a `LIKE` clause that can check whether there's a space missing before that pattern.

Comment: Good point Tim, yeah I think i'll do this in C#

Comment: Where did this data come from? Why aren't names and post codes separated? Was a newline removed perhaps? It's a *lot* easier to clean up the data while loading it

Comment: @Impaler DG1 is not a postcode, in the examples, G1 1DN is a postcode, and AB33 8NA is a postcode

Comment: What happens if you have an invalid postcode? For example, if someone enters D1O 3DC or E1 OBA?

Comment: Do you have a postcodes table?

Comment: `G1 1DN` (Glasgow) and `DG1 1DN` (Dumfries and Galloway) are both possible UK postcodes - so this would require knowledge that truncating at SALFORD is more likely than truncating at SALFOR